# Import the same .txt file into SQL Server database with a different name every week

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm currently importing the same `.txt` file into my SQL Server database once a week with a different name.

For example: I have a header file that I import into my SQL Server database, and call it `apple_april_02_09_2018`.

I then import the same `.txt` header file and call it `orange_april_02_09_2018`.

Next week I'll import the file again and call it `apple_april_09_16_2018` and `orange_april_09_16_2018`.

Is there a better way to do this besides manually using the import wizard every week?

Appreciate any help/insight!

Comment: Use MS SSIS tools

Comment: How do you "manually" import it every week? Do you run a program to parse and insert it?

Comment: Save the import wizard as a package and set to run weekly as a SQL Agent Job. It will be much easier if you use the same file name each week (or make a batch file to rename it automatically). @PhilNDeBlanc the user stated they are using the import wizard.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sql server data tools dynamic file name for flat file source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37009240/sql-server-data-tools-dynamic-file-name-for-flat-file-source)

Comment: @JacobH Ugh, I swear my reading comprehension is becoming questionable at best. I agree with your solution, BTW.